# Concatenate two integers in haskell

Tags: haskell

Hey guys I am having a problem with my code. The code below supposed to remove the first 2 in the list and then concatenate them.So the result answer would be 1,2.

```
first = [1,2,4,5,6,7] !! 0
second = [1,2,4,5,6,7] !! 1
newans = first ++ second
```

Comment: What do you mean with *remove*?

Comment: I think you want `newans = [first, second]`

Comment: `!!` is just an index operator: `[1,2,3]!!0 == 1`.

Comment: @4castle thanks your code worked for what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can not *remove* elements from a list: Haskell is declarative meaning once you construct a list `a`, `a` will always work with the *same* list.

You can however construct a *new* list without the first two elements, and create a new list with the first two elements. For example:

```
get_remove_2 :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
get_remove_2 (a:b:cs) = ([a,b],cs)
```

We thus construct a *new* list with the first two elements with the `[a,b]` expression.

This function will take as input a list `[a]` and return a 2-tuple with as first element a list with two elements: the first two elements of the original list, and as second element the list where the first two elements are not present.

Note that this function will only work if the given list contains *at least* two elements. Otherwise it will error.